# Does the demand for an index ETF make its stock price go up?

Tags: stocks, investing, etf, index-fund, investment-strategies

There are ETFs that follow an index. Let's say the classic S&P 500. We have two different ETFs following the same index. Let's say Vanguard and Schwab. 
Let's say Vanguard has much higher demand for some reason in a time range of 1 year. Will this 1 year the Vanguard ETF go up much faster than the other one even if they are following the same index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this would create an arbitrage which an authorized participant (AP) would quickly take advantage of. Worth reading up about the creation and redemption mechanism ([here](http://www.etf.com/etf-education-center/7540-what-is-the-etf-creationredemption-mechanism.html?nopaging=1) is a good place to start) to understand the exact way this happens in ETFs as it's very key to how they work.

Comment: Also just realized I missed this on your other ETF question so have just added it to the answer there about spreads and charges for simplicity...